# MYSQL DELETE row if duplicate key exists in same table with specified value

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, exists

This may be tagged as a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find this example in my search.

I have a product-to-category table that allows duplicate keys, therefore allowing products to be placed in multiple categories by ID. I have a situation where several thousand products were incorrectly placed in a category.  If the product is assigned to 'Action Figures' and 'Comics', then the 'Comics' assignation is erroneous.

I'm attempting to write a single MYSQL query that will delete rows if a row with a duplicate key and the specified value for 'Action Figures' is detected.  Another way to say it: If a product is assigned to both categories, then I want to delete the row assigning it to the erroneous category.

I can't seem to figure out a delete statement that can search within the same table by ID the way I want.

Here's what I've got so far (EDIT- Thanks to the answer below):

```
DELETE FROM oc_product_to_category c1
WHERE c1.category_id = '25'
AND EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM oc_product_to_category c2 
WHERE c1.product_id = c2.product_id AND c2.category_id = '24')
```

Unfortunately, this is producting a syntax error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'c1
WHERE c1.category_id = '25'
AND EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM oc_product_to_catego' at line 1
```

When I try the syntax

```
DELETE c1 FROM oc_product_to_category c1 ...
```

I get an error:

```
You can't specify target table 'c1' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.  If an ID is assigned to both category_id 25 and 33, it will delete the record(s) with category 25.

```
DELETE c1 FROM oc_product_to_category as c1
WHERE c1.category_id = '25'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM oc_product_to_category) as c2 
    WHERE c1.id = c2.id AND c2.category_id = '33'
)
```

Note that this won't remove duplicate records with category_id 33 if any exist.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could use 2 different aliases to refer to the same table... Ignorance strikes again.  And yes, the numbers are arbitrary, but I'm trying to repair the data.  The actual values are 25 and 33, but no worries.

Comment: It's a very useful tool for comparing values within a table. I've updated 26 to 33.  Also, please mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your question.

Comment: I've edited my question, getting a syntax error, and not sufficiently experienced with SQL to decipher it. Also, thank you for editing your answer.  The last sentence of my first comment was directed at another comment that has since been deleted.

Comment: Try the updated query in my answer.  I added a somewhat ugly work-around to a MySQL limitation that prevents modification of the same table used in the select statement.